# Converting nullable DateTime to NSDate after switching to Unfied API

Tags: c#, ios, datetime, xamarin, nsdate

I'm converting my app to support the new unified API of Xamarin.iOS. Here I want to use my old nullable `DateTime?` for setting the date of the datepicker:

```
datePicker.SetDate (someNullableDate, false);
```

On compiling I get the following error:

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `UIKit.UIDatePicker.SetDate(Foundation.NSDate, bool)' has some invalid
>   arguments (CS1502)

and

> Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`System.DateTime?'
>   expression to type `Foundation.NSDate' (CS1503)

This is how I instantiate *someNullableDate*:

```
DateTime? someNullableDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind (someNSDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Here I convert it back to `NSDate`:

```
if (someNullableDate != null && someNullableDate.HasValue) {
    DateTime someDate = someNullableDate.GetValueOrDefault ();
    NSDate someNSDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind (someDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
}
```

Currently all conversions are throwing an error. The classic API was able to do the conversion for me, but the unified API doesn't do that anymore because of data loss. In detail [Xamarin states](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating-tips/):

> The Unified API does not provide an implicit conversion between NSDate
>   and .NET DateTime because it's not a lossless conversion. To prevent
>   errors related to DateTimeKind.Unspecified convert the .NET DateTime
>   to local or UTC before casting to NSDate.

[Xamarin provided](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/) the following extension method:

```
public static DateTime NSDateToDateTime(this NSDate date)
{
    DateTime reference = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime( 
        new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) );
    return reference.AddSeconds(date.SecondsSinceReferenceDate);
}

public static NSDate DateTimeToNSDate(this DateTime date)
{
    DateTime reference = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(
        new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) );
    return NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate(
        (date - reference).TotalSeconds);
}
```

I tried adding `Nullable<DateTime>` in the arguments of the extension method for example, but this lead to more errors.

The conversion of `DateTime` should be possible with the provided extension method but how would you do that for nullable `DateTime`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem. The error is that it can`t convert Unspecified DateTimeKind, so solution is to convert DateTime first to **UTC**, or **LocalTime**:

```
if (someNullableDate != null && someNullableDate.HasValue) {
    DateTime someDate = someNullableDate.Value.ToUniversalTime();
    NSDate someNSDate = (NSDate)DateTime.SpecifyKind(someDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
}
```

Comment: you have a problem with your code. the SpecifyKind returns a DateTime and NOT a NSDate

Comment: Sorry for mistake, you also have to cast DateTime from SpecifyKind method to NSDate.